# Do elasticsearch doument participate in all OR conditions in bool query.?

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery, or-condition

I am new to Elasticsearch, And we are working on a requirement,where document in the elasticsearch will be fetched based on the **match types** like **fuzzyMatch,Wordmatch** etc...

We are facing performance issues here, when document is matched for one match type, document should come out of the **"bool"** query, but it is participating in all match types and giving me the all match types result, I tried **nested bool query** to make it participate in single match types and exit when matched else move to next match types.

I tried following this blog.

[https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query][1]

Even this is resulting me the same Reesult..

Please find the below sample code.

```
 {
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "4": {
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                            "query": "kavan",
                            "minimum_should_match": "50%",
                            "_name": "4.fuzzyMatch"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "4": {
                            "query": "kavan",
                            "minimum_should_match": "50%",
                            "_name": "4.wordMatch"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "4.subStringMatch": {
                            "query": "kavan",
                            "minimum_should_match": "50%",
                            "_name": "4.subStringMatch"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "4.phoneticMatch": {
                            "query": "kavan",
                            "minimum_should_match": "50%",
                            "_name": "4.phoneticMatch"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "4.exactMatch": "kavan"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Actual output is:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 94,
    "max_score": 50.0,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "6_1028",
      "_type": "6_1028",
      "_id": "14",
      "_score": 50.0,
      "_source": {
        "1": 14,
        "@timestamp": "2018-05-18T06:57:02.540Z",
        "4": "kavana",
        "6": "Vastrad",
        "7": "Indiranagar",
        "@version": "1",
        "type": "1028",
        "10": "Bangalore"
      },
      "matched_queries": ["4.phoneticMatch", "4.fuzzyMatch", "4.subStringMatch"]
    }, {
      "_index": "6_1028",
      "_type": "6_1028",
      "_id": "52",
      "_score": 50.0,
      "_source": {
        "1": 52,
        "@timestamp": "2018-05-18T06:57:02.559Z",
        "4": "kavana",
        "6": "Vastrad",
        "7": "Indiranagar",
        "@version": "1",
        "type": "1028",
        "10": "Bangalore"
      },
      "matched_queries": ["4.phoneticMatch", "4.fuzzyMatch", "4.subStringMatch"]
    }, {
      "_index": "6_1028",
      "_type": "6_1028",
      "_id": "53",
      "_score": 50.0,
      "_source": {
        "1": 53,
        "@timestamp": "2018-05-18T06:57:02.559Z",
        "4": "kavana",
        "6": "Vastrad",
        "7": "Indiranagar",
        "@version": "1",
        "type": "1028",
        "10": "Bangalore"
      },
      "matched_queries": ["4.phoneticMatch", "4.fuzzyMatch", "4.subStringMatch"]
    }
}
```

Expected output is:

```
 "hits": {
    "total": 94,
    "max_score": 50.0,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "6_1028",
      "_type": "6_1028",
      "_id": "14",
      "_score": 50.0,
      "_source": {
        "1": 14,
        "@timestamp": "2018-05-18T06:57:02.540Z",
        "4": "kavana",
        "6": "Vastrad",
        "7": "Indiranagar",
        "@version": "1",
        "type": "1028",
        "10": "Bangalore"
      },
      "matched_queries": ["4.phoneticMatch"]
    }
```

With only one match type in **matched_queries**

Note : Match types can be seen in **matched_queries** block.

Any suggestions in this regard are appreciated..